# disadvatages of local web server on rooted android tablet?

Tags: php, android, tomcat, web, tablet

I have two web applications, one use java/tomcat/postgresql,
another php/mysql. I need to run them in offline mode on tablet.
Thus I have to make decision rewrite them into ordinal android applications, or use `as is`.

So, do you see any big disadvantages in compare with ordinal Android app, in installation
oracle jvm, php, mysql, postgresql prebuilded for arm cpu into rooted android? Note, that web application will have only one user/client in such case.

For example power consummation or cpu usage?

As I understand, because of usage of loopback device,
no power loss for 3G/LTE/Wifi. Because of php/tomcat work
only during http request, not big power or cpu usage?

And as understand open sockets on loopback device to not prevent go into low-power mode.

The only difference in compare to ordinal android application as I understand will be more big memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, for the effort you would need to go to in rooting the device, installing required services/software and then maintaining it, surely it would be much better to rewrite it as an android app or maybe use something like cordova.  This has the added advantage of being easier to roll out to multiple devices should the need arise.

Answer (score 1):

Ehm...

> I have two web applications, one use java/tomcat/postgresql, another php/mysql. I need to run them in offline mode on tablet. Thus I have to make decision rewrite them into ordinal android applications, or use as is.

If you want to run something locally in an Android device then you have to make them run as an Android app. Or as part of one.

> So, do you see any big disadvantages in compare with ordinal Android app, in installation oracle jvm, php, mysql, postgresql prebuilded for arm cpu into rooted android? Note, that web application will have only one user/client in such case.

If whoever is going to use this doesn't mind about the *huge* overhead (relative to usual portable devices capabilities), then it's fine. I don't see this happening, though.

Look, I don't want to sound rude, but who gave you such a *silly* idea? (trying too hard to not say something else over here). The programs you mention were clearly not intended for execution inside such a device. Some of them might even need a full rewrite in order to even launch.

Going into details, some of the disadvantages are these:

- **Higher CPU and RAM consumption**, specially RAM. And you need power to keep data in RAM so...
- **Higher battery consumption**, due to the first. And the fact you would be actually running several applications instead of one.
- **One of the required technologies might (*will*) not work**. Android does not bring your usual Oracle Java SE VM with JIT Compillation and like 3 garbage collectors to choose from, it uses either Dalvik VM or that new one whose name I don't remember. The default public libraries and APIs are different. Even the internal OS doesn't bring all the binaries a standard Linux distro does, and you would need an app like BusyBox in order to install them.
- **Will surely require root**. Users are often discouraged of rooting their devices because they usually end up bricking them, one way or another, and because it voids any active guarantee. Good luck convincing them to do it without saying the phrase "free gems for Clash Royale" at least once.
- **Those technologies are intended for use by several users**. What's the point of going full client/server if only one user will use the server?

Besides, you have Java, C and SQLite at your disposal, all out of the box and properly optimized for use in mobile devices. Why not use that in a mobile device application?

Finally, I'm not saying that what you have in mind is impossible, because technically it *should* be possible, but is that effort *worth* it?

Comment: It is not big effort, after root device, I can install ubuntu for arm in chroot, and one command install normal jvm, php and other stuff, just `apt-get install` and thats all. Advantages are clear: we don't have to rewrite software, just use it as is. So my question is more about power usage, cpu usage and so on things.

Comment: Well, yes, the CPU/RAM/Battery issue would persist. And you would be likely to need a custom ROM in order to get enough storage space to install those tools and platforms you want to deploy your app in (or maybe not, depending of the situation). Another issue is how usable will be the web app in a tablet, considering if the GUI is responsive or not, among other things. If the user is really willing to go through all that, then besides the overhead and setup there shouldn't be so many obstacles.